# how do you convert binary to decimal

Tags: computational-complexity

Suppose I have computed $\pi$ to 4 trillion binary digits
(1 trillion hex digits).  I want to convert to decimal. You could remove the leading $11_2=3_{10}$ and then multiply the  remaining number by $10_{10} = 1010_2$.  Then remove the leading digit $1$ and multiply the remain number by $10_{10}$ again and so on.  A  slightly faster way is to multiply by $100_{10} = 1100100_2$ and get two digits each time.  But this is very slow.  It would take years to do the job.  Is there a fast way that a computer or 1000 computers could do the job in a reasonable length of time?

Comment: Dear Bob, you might try posting questions of this flavour or level on http://math.stackexchange.com Probably questions on $E_0$-semigroups would get a better reception here...

Comment: (FWIW I also think the number of downvotes is excessive, although closure is probably reasonable)

Comment: I would be curious for specific reasons this question was downvoted and put on hold. Probably I am just ignorant about numerical algorithms but I'm curious about the fastest algorithms for this. I was thinking of something like arithmetic coding, where we try to maintain decimal upper- and lower-bounds on the number, which we gradually narrow as we read more bits (e.g. between 3.14 and 3.15, then between 3.141 and 3.142 [allows us to output the '4'], etc.). Not sure of the complexity but seems like it should be faster than the naive approach above.

Comment: @usul, the first challenge was to avoid (if possible) acting on the whole number globally. That was done in my algorithm from 1984, see below.  The computation is localized to one digit at the time (I used $\ 256=2^8\ $ as the base because it was only those relatively early years).

Comment: @usul It's hard to say. One may argue that this question belongs to computational mathematics, but even then it is probably not of research level. So I would say this question is off-topic. For your interest in a fast algorithm, see e.g. http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/internals/radix-conversion.html.

Answer (score 2):

During early 1984, I've visited BGSU, and on a side, I'd developed for a friend a limited *infinite precision* program in C, which was comparing the efficiency of professional investors (later, I learned that my approach was known). I hope that you will manage to make sense of my subroutine. It avoided global operations on the whole array which represented a very long integer, it was dealing only with one digit at the time.

Actually, my digits (the counting system) were base 256, i.e. my input array had integers from $\ 0\ $ to $\ 255\ $ as the digits of the very long integer represented by the array.

> 

**REMARK** My program used constant   five_to_8 $\, :=\, 5^8.$

> **Subroutine in C (by W.H.)**

long bin_to_dec(ds, dpr)

long ds[ ], dpr;

{

long n,i,carry,aux;

for(n=dpr-1; n>=0; n--)

{

carry = 0;

for(i=0; i < n; i++)

{

aux = five_to_8 * ds[i] + carry;

carry = aux >> 8;

ds[i] = aux & 255;

}

ds[n] = five_to_8 * ds[n] + carry;

}

}

> *Enjoy.*

Comment: Do you have an estimate of how long this would run? As far as I understand, we have to deal with dpr $\approx 1$ trillion, and the algorithm needs about dpr$^2$ operations. So if we have a 1 Teraflop processor, even if I give a couple of orders of magnitude for floating point vs. bit, that sounds like well over billions of seconds, i.e., decades ... am I missing something?

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt, my short reaction: you're right. For the given application, my program was very fast, my "very long integers" were not that long. It was simply an application project, not theoretical. ## I was extra careful to avoid any bugs in a short time devoted to the project -- I used a very safe base $\ 2^8\ $ for avoiding any overflow carry problems. The standard was 16-bit computers, and I used C's double-precision. Today's 64-bit computers would allow base $\ 2^{16}$-base even with the single precision. This would cut the execution time about 4++ times, still not satisfactory yet.